# Assuming independent events, compute the probability that exactly one of three flight are overbooked.

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question:**

Sky High Airlines operates flights from your local airport to Orlando, to Tampa, and to Miami. The probability of the flight to Orlando being overbooked equal to 30%, the probability of the flight to Tampa being overbooked equal to 15%, and the probability of the flight to Miami being overbooked equal to 25%. Assume that these events of overbooking are independent events.

•Compute the probability that all the flights are overbooked.

•Compute the probability of having at least one flight which is not overbooked.

•Compute the probability that exactly one flight is overbooked.

**Notes**

This material is meant to strengthen your knowledge of the law of total probability.

Where I am struggling is turning the words into math. I feel like I'm missing something.

P(Overbooked|Orlando) = 0.3
P(Overbooked|Tampa) = 0.15
P(Overbooked|Miami) = 0.25

I feel like I should be using one of these formulas...

(AnB)  =  P(A|B)*P(B)

P(A)   =  P(A∩B)+P(A∩Bc)  =  P(A∣B)P(B)+P(A∣Bc)P(Bc)

But I feel like i should have been given a probability of selecting a certain flight P(Orlando), P(Tampa), P(Miami). Or should I be focusing on complements like...

P(Overbooked'|Orlando) = 0.7
P(Overbooked'|Tampa) = 0.85
P(Overbooked'|Miami) = 0.75

**Current Best Guesses**

- *Compute the probability that all the flights are overbooked.*
  0.3 * 0.15 * 0.25  = 0.01125
- *Compute the probability of having **at least one** flight which is not overbooked.* Sum of the probability of the following possible outcomes: 
  {O, T', M'} {O', T, M'} {O', T', M} {O, T, M'} {O, T', M} {O', T, M} {O, T, M}
  *Is this just 1-P(all overbooked)?
- *Compute the probability that exactly one flight is overbooked*
  Sum of the probability of the following possible outcomes: 
  {O, T', M'} {O', T, M'} {O', T', M}

If someone can just point me in the right direction, that would be great. I feel like it will be painfully obvious what I'm missing but I've been staring this thing down for far too long.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Your approach to all three problems is correct.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You're right; but for the second task I would calculate $1-P(O'T'M')$.

Answer (score 1):

If the events are independent, then $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) P(B) P(C)$. In other words, you can just multiply the probabilities.

In this case, you want $P(\textrm{exactly one of} \{A, B, C\})$, which is the same as $P(A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C) + P(\neg A \cap B \cap \neg C) + P(\neg A \cap \neg B \cap C)$. (Bonus: why can we add the probabilities here? What property of the events allows this?)

Since you know the probabilities of each event, and $P(\neg X) = 1 - P(X)$, now you just have to do a whole lot of multiplication and addition to find your answer!